# Getting the current search term from select2 input

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to get the current search term value (even if it is not matched) from a select2 input.

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi form-control" id="s2id_author">
    <ul class="select2-choices">  
        <li class="select2-search-field">    
            <label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen1" placeholder="" style="width: 34px;" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-2">  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Select2 are you actually using? And where are you trying to get this text?

Answer (score 9):

This one is working for me in 4.0+

```javascript
var nome = $("#select2_id").data('select2').$dropdown.find("input").val();
```

Comment: If you hit `$("#select2_id").data('select2')` in console, you would be seen available options like `$dropdown` which you can access for further manipulation over actual `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
$(selector)
  .data("select2")
  .search[0]
  .value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below, it may help your need

```
var InputSelector = '#e1',
select2 = $(InputSelector).data('select2'),
searchedInput = select2.search;
```

Answer (score 1):

Works with v4.0.5

```
$('#select2_id').find('.select2-search__field').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this worked for me**

```
$('#select2').data("select2").$dropdown.find('.select2-search__field').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('input.select2-input').val();
```

this will get you the first value in a set of values

My question back to you is, are there more than one 'Select2-Input' fields on your form?

Comment: No just one select2 input.  I'm trying your suggestion and it simply returns undefined.  How do I capture the entered text as its being entered?

Comment: ok enter that added information in your original question please, and I  appreciate your quick response

Comment: the as it is being entered is very relevant and changes the question.  Now you will need a function to act upon

Comment: I do not see the Data configuration settings for a select2 textbox either, I believe Beginners answer alludes to the use of "DATA-* " attributes

Answer (score 0):

`$(selector).data("select2").results.lastParams.term`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to get the last search term:

```
$(selector).data('select2').lastSearchTerm
```